# Positional Only Parameter Syntax '/' in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Firstly, I'm using Python 3.11.0 in Colab.

When I use `/` to make parameters positional-only, `SyntaxError` is raised.

However, when I use `*` for keyword-only parameters, any error hasn't been raised.

Is there anyone who knows why these things happen?

```
# SyntaxError is raised
def foo(x, y, /):
    return x + y
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-28-57597574dc0a>", line 1
    def foo(x, y, /):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
# This was ok
def foo(*, x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: I can't repro, are you sure you are running 3.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python introduces the new function syntax in Python3.8.2 Version, Where we can introduce the / forward slash to compare the positional only parameter which comes before the / slash and parameters that comes after * is keyword only arguments. Rest of the arguments that are come between / and * can be either positional or keyword type of argument.

Google colab  version :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found why `/` was not working. I thought I upgraded python to 3.11.0 because the result of `!python --version` was `Python 3.11.0`, but the version of runtime python was 3.7.15.

Answer (score 0):

I try with Python 3.10 kernel and it works fine.

See this notebook.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rNF0KhX2A2UwazoYuUGeikCJm2YGxcgg